# Why don't my domain transitions don't occur when the application binary is outside of the stardard binary directories?

Tags: linux, selinux

I'm trying to set up a custom `SELinux` policy, but I'm having trouble getting the domain transitions to occur when the application binary is outside of the standard binary directories such as `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc. It is necessary that the application binary is located outside of those directories.

For testing purposes, I have a program that simply prints the current `SELinux` domain. I have a domain `my_domain_t`, and a type `my_domain_exec_t`. A transition to `my_domain_t` is set up to occur when a process in the `unconfined_t` domain executes a file with the `my_domain_exec_t` context.

If I copy the test binary to the `/data` directory, set its context, and execute it, the domain does not change.

```
$ cp getcontext /data/getcontext
$ chcon -t my_domain_exec_t /data/getcontext
$ /data/getcontext
unconfined_t:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

If I instead copy the test binary to the `/usr/bin` directory, set its context, and then execute it, the domain transition occurs correctly.

```
$ sudo cp getcontext /usr/bin/getcontext
$ sudo chcon -t my_domain_exec_t /usr/bin/getcontext
$ /usr/bin/getcontext
unconfined_t:unconfined_r:my_domain_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Through testing, I believe I've eliminated anything to do with the user running the files, the ownership of the files, or the security context of the parent directory. What else could be causing this difference?

**Edit:** 
`/data` is not NFS-mounted.
The context of `/data` is `system_u:object_r:default_t:s0`.
On another system I've been testing on I've also see `/data` labeled `system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0`.

```
policy_module(my_domain, 1.0.0)

require {
    type unconfined_t;
}

type my_domain_t;
type my_domain_exec_t;

role unconfined_r types my_domain_t;

allow unconfined_t my_domain_exec_t:file *;
allow my_domain_t my_domain_exec_t:file { rx_file_perms() };

allow unconfined_t my_domain_t:process { transition siginh setexec };
type_transition unconfined_t my_domain_exec_t: process my_domain_t;
```

This the simplest of the nearly 20 versions of the policy I've created, and it displays the described behavior. I've also tried the `domain_trans`, `domain_auto_trans`, and `domain_entry_file` macros, as well as generating the policy with the `sepolgen` tool, which used the `domtrans_pattern` macro.

Comment: Please re-run and provide the output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -m user_avc -m selinux_err`

Answer (score 2):

SElinux does not really care so much about file paths.

I am unable to duplicate your problem.
I am using a `staff_r` role and `staff_t` type on Fedora 20, but this seems to effectively replicate your issue.

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <selinux/selinux.h>

int main() {
  security_context_t con;

  if (getcon(&con) < 0) {
    perror("Cannot getcon");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("%s\n", con);
  freecon(con);

  return 0;
}
```

My policy.

```
policy_module(getcon, 1.0.0)

require {
  role staff_r;
  type staff_t;
}

## Type defs
type getcon_exec_t;
type getcon_t;
application_domain(getcon_t, getcon_exec_t)

## Role permits
role staff_r types getcon_t;

## Transitions
domain_auto_transition_pattern(staff_t, getcon_exec_t, getcon_t);

## Access vectors
allow getcon_t staff_t:process sigchld;

userdom_use_inherited_user_ptys(getcon_t);
```

To compile program:

```
gcc -o getcon getcon.c -lselinux
```

To compile and load policy:

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile load
```

Running without changing the context

```
$ ./getcon
staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Changing the context:

```
# chcon -t getcon_exec_t getcon
$ ./getcon
staff_u:staff_r:getcon_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Changing the parent directory to default_t:

```
# chcon -t . default_t; chcon -t getcon_exec_t getcon
$ ./getcon
staff_u:staff_r:getcon_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

You can try using my policy as a basis if you like. But this doesn't seem to affect me.